# Changing group of php-fpm

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu-18.04, php-7.2

I want to execute php-fpm (7.2) with another group while staying in the original groups.

Currently php-fpm runs with *www-data* as user and group. I've created a new group (*testgrp*) and added the user *www-data* to the group.

*www-data* has gid: 33
*testgrp* has gid: 144

For a spawned PHP-process, `/proc/PID/status` gives me:

```
Uid:    33  33  33  33
Gid:    33  33  33  33
Groups: 33 144
```

which shows that php runs with *www-data* as user and main group, but is also in *testgrp*.

When I set `group = testgrp` in `/etc/php/7.2/fpm/pool.d/www.conf`, I get:

```
Uid:    33  33  33  33
Gid:    144 144 144 144
Groups: 144
```

so php runs with *testgrp* as only group.

Is there a way to change the executing group without loosing the membership of *www-data*?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? I.e. the end goal, see http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: @chelmertz I'd like to match iptable rules for outgoing communication of php (i.e. gid-owner) without having to mess too much with the file-groups of the files php is accessing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after looking into the source-code of php-fpm, I found the solution:

I had to add the user *www-data* to the *www-data* group (again).
Even though *www-data* is the primary group of user *www-data*, it has to be assigned in `/etc/group`, because php-fpm uses the groups from `/etc/group` + the provided group while ignoring the primary group.